# How is soft switching in a PMSM inverter achieved?

Tags: inverter, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, pmsm, zvs

Recently I found some papers about PMSM drives that use the regular circuit of 6 e.g. IGBTs to drive a permanent magnet synchronous motor but with a resonant circuit in front of it to achieve zero voltage switching.

I understand that the idea with the resonant circuit is to reduce the voltage to zero at certain times to switch on or off the power switches. What I don't understand is, how the current for the motor will look like.

It must have quite a high sinusoidal ripple if the resonant frequency is greater than the PMSM excitation frequency. If both frequencies are equal, I don't understand how a 3-phase rotating field can be generated. From my point of view, it would make sense to turn on only to power switches at the same time, what would lead to more or less a 6-step control and not to a field-oriented control of the PMSM.

Does anyone know how this works and if the resonant frequency is equal or greater than the PMSM rotating field frequency? Unfortunately I only found papers about this at IEEE, if anyone can recommend more sources on this topic, even if they're not free, I would be thankful.

Here is one example for a current fed soft switching inverter, others can be found here:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5138826

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9124700
[image: example:]